# Used IFERROR to use VLOOKUP across 10 sheets, but the data displayed is not accurate

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

So far, my code as is gives me a #NAME? error that I have not been able to fix.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'A1-U2'I$A$3:$B$262325,2,TRUE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'U2-U3'I$A$3:$B$237677,2,TRUE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'U3-U4'I$A$1:$B$281070, 
2,FALSE), IFERROR (VLOOKUP (B2, 'U4-U5'ISA$1:$B$218930,2,TRUE),IFERROR (VLOOKUP(B2, 'U5-UG'ISA$1:$B$267280,2,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, 'UG'ISA$1:
$B$232740,2,TRUE), FERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, 'U6-U7 I$A$1:$B$281065,2,TRUE), IFERROR (VLOOKUP(B2, 'U7 ISA$1:$B$218935,2, TRUE), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'U7-U8'!
$A$1:$B$250729,2,TRUE), IFERROR (VLOOKUP(B2, 'U8-U9'I$A$1:$B$221835,2,TRUE), "Not Available"))))))))))
```

When I switch the FALSE for TRUE, the code does seem to work, but gives a random set of numbers from the column I need that doesn't match the information provided in the VLOOKUP. What should I change or do better?

Comment: In what is the 5th line of your formula (as viewed on a desktop) the 'function' at the start of that line is FERROR, rather than IFERROR

Comment: You also seem to be missing some !, e.g. the first lookup area is defined as 'A1-U2'I$A$3:$B$262325, when it probably should be defined as 'A1-U2'!$A$3:$B$262325 (exclamation point instead of vertical bar)
Similarly, a you have a few S characters which should instead be $ characters

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far, I've solved both issues with syntax but I still apparently get the same issue only when using FALSE. Update:  I was using the wrong version of the quotation marks on my code. Thank you.